# Click event on bar chart and gradient color MP chart library

Tags: android, bar-chart

[image]

I have a made the bar chart it is almost done, just I need a popup as shown in the image above on click of every item, how can I achieve this. I tried referring to `https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart`

But I can't understand. Also how can I add gradient colors in the bar chart?

Comment: You need to use MarkerView for this and need to highlight the values.

Answer (score 1):

When You initialize your graph, Use the following code to show marker view

```
MarkerView mv = new MarkerView(mContext, R.layout.chart_marker);
    mv.setChartView(graph); // For bounds control i.e graph
    graph.setMarker(mv); // Set marker
    graph.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
    graph.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
```

Here R.layout.chart_marker is optional, this is used for custom layout. You can remove this one.

It will show marker over your bar chart.

Comment: Refer this link : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivity.java